# CLabel Displaying box characters in the text if it exceeds its control height - MFC?

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have a text to be displayed on dialog. I used CLabel which extends CStatic Class.
Problem is, if i have to display multi-line in CLabel considering, it can adjust up to two lines. if i have to enter third line i used DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS flag so that text is displayed in second line itself by appending  ellipsis to it. everything works fine but, some small rectangle box characters are displayed when third line is appended. is it problem with \n? please help :o

Comment: Did you try to remove the \n in order to look if the small rectabgle box disapears ?

Comment: see in edit control iam entering some text which includes \n \t  etc.. iam capturing it and trying to display in CLabel. ya when it exceeds the control height ideally text in the third line should not be seen.
but iam assigning DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS style to CLabel so that text in third line concatenates to second by appending with ellipses..

i forgot to mention this issue only seen in xp machine in vista and windows7 it is not seen. please help.